# How to add AWS Fargate service and google cloud run services under same security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, security-groups, aws-fargate

I have a web application which consists of an api gateway and two microservices. I want the microservices to remain hidden from the outside world and only the api gateway should be able to access the microservices.
The api gateway container is deployed on serverless amazon fargate and the microservices are deployed on google cloud run serverless.
How to put the aws fargate in the same security group as the cloud run services so that only the gateway has access to these services?

Answer (score 1):

First, create a service account at [console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts). Then add it to your Cloud Run service at `console.cloud.google.com/run/detail/<your-service-region>/<your-service-name>/permissions`. Then create a key for it as described in [cloud.google.com/iam/docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys). Then use the service account key in your API gateway in Fargate to connect to your Cloud Run service, as described in [cloud.google.com/docs/authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually).

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you